# Compiling R package in parallel on multiple platforms

Tags: r, windows, macos, compilation, parallel-processing

I am developing a new R package using Rcpp. 
We reached the point were compile times become significantly long.

So I was wondering how to compile an R package in parallel.
We develop on Linux, OSX and Windows for max compatability and so far I was only able to answer my question for Linux (sudo MAKE="make -j8" R CMD INSTALL package).

Can some one tell me how to do the same thing on a Windows and OSX system?

thanks
Cedric

Comment: I am also wondering this